# How to use destructors on arrays of derived objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor, virtual-destructor

I have a three theoretical questions regarding virtual destructors:
lets assume I have a base class `Base` - two derived classes `Derivative_1` and `Derivative_2`, class `Stand_Alone` and class `Project`.
class `Stand_Alone` is used a a private member both in `Base` and `Project`.
class `Project` has the private members: objects of `Derivative_1`, a dynamic array of `Derivative_2` objects and a `Stand_Alone` object.
for the example lets assume that only one `Project` object is created in the main.

1. is the destructor of `Project` correct - de-allocating all dynamic memory of an object?
2. should the destructor of `Base` be declared as `virtual`?
3. the destructors of `Derivative_1` and `Derivative_2` shouldn't be declared as `virtual`, right?

thanks.

```
#ifndef PROJECT_H
#define PROJECT_H
#include "Stand_Alone.h"
#include "Derivative_1.h"
#include "Derivative_2.h"

class Project
{
public:
    Project();
    ~Project()
{
    delete [] support;
    support = NULL;
}
 protected:
 private:
    Stand_Alone member;
    Derivative_1 head;
    Derivative_2 *support;
};

#endif // PROJECT_H
```

Comment: 1. Can't say without seeing more code. But you don't need to set the pointer to NULL. 2. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. is the destructor of `Project` correct - de-allocating all dynamic memory of an object?

Yes, although there are safer ways of doing that. You could declare a vector of `Derivative_2` objects instead of manipulating the memory yourself. This way you wouldn't need to declare a destructor at all, since the default destructor provided by your compiler would do the job pretty well.

> 1. should the destructor of `Base` be declared as `virtual`?

Yes, this is the only way to make sure that it will be called when objects of either its subclasses are destroyed.

Comment: Note: 1. You can't say without knowing how the thing the pointer points to was created. 2. This only matters when the object gets destroyed by calling `delete` on a pointer to the base class.